# find the prime numbers in C

Tags: c

I have this code for prime numbers..it gives me the prime numbers up to 103.Maybe my first break statement is wrong? I did it this way because i want to skip as much numbers as possible.i want only the primes that have at least two digits(that is why i started from 11)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUMB 100000000
int main (void)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 11 ; i < MAXNUMB ; i += 2)
    {
        if ((i % 3 == 0) && (i % 5 == 0) && (i % 7 == 0))
            break;
        for (j = 3 ; j * j <= i ; j += 2)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (j * j > i)
            printf ("%d \n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is wrong. It will break if the number is divisible by 3 *and* 5 *and* 7. But that's not the problem. Using a debugger you'd see that breaking is not the way to go.

Comment: `num = i` is Undefined Behavior, `i` was not initialized at the moment of `num = i`.

Comment: why did you declare so many integers while you used i and j?

Comment: @iharob opss sorry about that..i edited it

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes i checked it.With `continue` ..it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXNUMB 100000000
int main (void)
{
    int i, j, P[MAXNUMB];
    memset(P, 0, sizeof(P));
    for(i = 2; i < MAXNUMB; ++i)
    {
        if(P[i] == 0){
           printf("%d\n", i);
           if(i < MAXNUMB / i)
              for(j = i*i; j < MAXNUMB; j += i)
                 P[j] = 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry @kostasdi I don't have and IDE or a way to run this, but if say where is the error I will fix it... it is a fastest way comparing with my previous one.

Comment: it has two small mistakes .it is not `MAX` but `MAXNUMB` and second in `printf` it is `\n` not `\d`

Comment: try now @kostasdi I changed for mistake a var name

Comment: yes it is working now.i think..because everytime i try to compile it..it says primes.exe stop working!Maybe my compiler is not strong enough

Comment: you can use some program like `time` in linux systems to compare execution time of both solutions. happy hacking

Comment: if it is possible one last question.with my way(i mean without using arrays)we can make it faster?

Comment: I think no, but don't worry about that.. this solution is used on some contest of ACM-ICPC. there are some others approatch faster than my own :)

Comment: I don't get it.  contents of array `P` are undefined. why do you use it for comparison?

Comment: @RegisteredUser this array can be declared globally and then its defaults values will be zero, or can be filled with memset or some other function to set defaults values to zero.

Answer (score 4):

Use `continue` rather then `break`;  Here you want to skip much number ( As if there are many ways to find the prime numbers in small complexity like much popular [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)) but it breaks. So change a little..

```
 if((i%3==0)&& ( i%5==0) && (i%7==0))

            continue;// here
```

it works..

Answer (score 0):

As it would be obvious using a debugger, that statement is wrong. First, you check for numbers that are divisible by 3 *and* 5 *and* 7. 105 is divisible by all. Then you break, which means "exit this for loop", so the program will end. You need to just continue the looping and not report this number as a prime.

You want to change the loop to use *or* instead of *and*. Also the next for loop doesn't need to start from 3 then, since you already tried 3, 5, 7. But is there a reason for that since you could just use the for loop?

My suggestion would be to just forget the first if altogether since it will not make it any faster.

Comment: i just want to find a very fast way to check all the primes.so i must find a way to skip numbers which are for sure not primes

Comment: @kostasdi But your second loop already tests 3, 5 and 7 first so the speed up of testing them separately is quite small. But at least start the next loop from 11 then and not from 3.

Comment: you are right about 11. i forgot to mention that i want all the primes that have at least 2 digits.i will edit it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXNUMB 100000000
int main (void)
{
    int i, j, f;
    for (i = 11; i < MAXNUMB; i += 2)
    {
       for (j = 2, f = 1; f && j * j < i; ++j)
       {
          f = (i % j != 0);
       }
       if (f) printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kostasdi take a look to my last solution, is faster than it.